# Передача объекта PyArrayObject в С

Tags: python, c

Создаю в Python черный RGB-кадр размером 720x576 (левый верхний угол закрашен другим цветом для проверки в C функции после передачи в нее этого кадра). Фрагмент кода python:

```
initial_frame = np.zeros((576, 720, 3))
for s1 in range(0, 20):
    for s2 in range(0, 20):
       initial_frame[s1][s2][0] = 80
       initial_frame[s1][s2][1] = 50
       initial_frame[s1][s2][2] = 120
SpecialFuncs.read_frame(initial_frame)
```

Далее кадр считывается в функции read_frame():

```
static PyObject* py_read_frame(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
PyArrayObject *dst_rgb;
unsigned char *p_data = NULL;
npy_intp *size;
int n_row, n_col, n_strides;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &dst_rgb))
   return Py_BuildValue("i", -5);

p_data = (unsigned char *)PyArray_DATA(dst_rgb);
if (!p_data)
   return Py_BuildValue("i", -6);

size = PyArray_DIMS(dst_rgb);
n_row = size[0];
n_col = size[1];
n_strides = size[2];

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < n_row; j1++) { //rows
   for (int j2 = 0; j2 < n_col; j2++) { //columns
      if ((p_data[j1 * n_col * 3 + j2 * 3] == 80) || 
            (p_data[j1 * n_col * 3 + j2 * 3 + 1] == 80) || 
               (p_data[j1 * n_col * 3 + j2 * 3 + 2] == 80))
                  return Py_BuildValue("i", j1);
           }
      }
return Py_BuildValue("i", -7); 
}
```

Я ожидаю найти первый закрашенный пиксель, но я его не вижу (функция проходит полностью цикл, не находя число 80). Такое впечатление, что указатель p_data смотрит не туда. При этом количество строк, столбцов и величина шага верные (n_row = 576, n_col = 720, n_strides = 3). Буду весьма признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вам нужно использовать `shape=(3, 576, 720)`.

Вы ожидаете, что цветовые компоненты будут храниться в ячейке матрицы, но на самом деле у Вас будет несколько матриц, каждая размером MxN, и в каждой будет храниться конкретная цветовая компонента.

> Вы ожидаете, что цветовые компоненты будут храниться в ячейке матрицы

Вывод сделан из предложенной Вами индексации: `p_data[j1 * n_col * 3 + j2 * 3]`

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, 
Вы имеете в виду писать numpy.zeros(shape=(576, 720, 2))?
Это не совсем верно, т.к. shape для подобных кадров = (576, 720, 3).
Правильно ли я понял идею, что в памяти цветовые компоненты хранятся не друг за другом, поэтому индексация в цикле неверная? В таком случае возникает вопрос, на что указывает p_data. Если это указатель на начало массива байтов, образующих матрицы, то, отсканировав весь массив, я должен был где-нибудь найти на число 80, однако этого не случилось. Такое может произойти, если матрицы не образуют непрерывную область памяти.

Comment: @j12, ой, извините, я по невнимательности 2-ку написал. Кончено же там должна быть 3-ка. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @j12, такое могло произойти и в том случае, если Вы неправильно проинициализировали элементы матрицы.